# Socket Issue on Unix, but the same code works on Windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, sockets, unix

I have the java program below that works when executed on windows 8, but when I publish the program to a unix server, it does not work and throws a timeout on `din.read()`  method.

```
socket2 = new Socket (ip, porta);
socket2.setSoTimeout(3000);

PrintStream pout = new PrintStream ( socket2.getOutputStream() );
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream( socket2.getInputStream() );
pout.println("GST"); //I am not sure if the other side is receiving this command
pout.flush();

int retint = din.read(); //here is the timeout
System.out.println( retint );
fechaSocket(socket2);
return ""+ retint;
```

Comment: Well what's the other end doing? If it's waiting for a `\r\n` to terminate the command, that would probably explain it...

Comment: After how much time you're getting the timeout?

Comment: What port number are you listening on?

Comment: Are both cases talking to the same server? On the same host?

Comment: And does the server happen to be running on the same Windows machine that you tested the Windows client on?  (If so, could be the firewall.)